# Why there are showing Two Storyboards in my every new xcode project?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, storyboard, viewcontroller

Whenever I am trying to open a new project xcode always giving two story board and two View controller one DataViewController instead of showing one view controller and one story board .

I am using xcode 7.3.1

my versity hood was an old project of min which has only one view controller but 
 when i create new project everytime now i get two view controller like alamofire project. Point to be noted that it has started to happen after cocoapods installation and alamofire installation
please If any one knows how to fix it please help.

[image][image]

Comment: Which project are you creating? (Single view app, master detail.....)

Comment: There will **ALWAYS** be two storyboards namely Main.storyboard and LaunchScreen.storyboard. Depending on the template you choose to work upon, the view controllers in the **Main.storyboard** differ.

Comment: @Dershowitz123 i have two storyboard in Main.storyboard :(

Comment: Can you please post a screenshot of it please?

Comment: @Dershowitz123 i have added the pictures please if you can help me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've chosen a wrong template. You need to choose `Single View Application` while creating your project. That gives you two storyboards and one view controller in **Main.storyboard** to start with. You have only 2 storyboards like normal. You just two `ViewControllers` and two `ViewController` classes. Nothing to worry. Just create a new project and select `Single View Application` in the beginning when it asks you to choose a template. It'll be fine.

Comment: thank you very much.. one more question can you give me some usefull link to learn ios perfectly??

Comment: It's all [here](https://itunes.apple.com/in/book/swift-programming-language/id881256329?mt=11) . I'm a beginner too :) .

Answer (score 2):

Are you talking about LaunchScreen.storyboard?  If so, that is a special one (that can't be associated with code) that is used to draw something on the screen while your app is loading.

A common thing to do is to draw a version of your start screen with no controls (or all controls disabled) and no data yet (so it looks like it's loading).

Another common thing to do is some kind of splash screen.

Comment: i have two storyboard in Main.storyboard  I have added screen shots and added more details ...please help me out